# How to select/mark a whole paragraph in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, mark, paragraphs

I have the following paragraph inside an `.org` file:

```
Observation: Currently, this feature is not part of the last stable
release (version 2.2.4). Thus, users can only access it while running
the application directly from source. To do that, please read the manual.
```

There is an empty line after and before this snippet. I was looking for some command similar to `mark-sexp`.

How can I mark (select) the whole paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is the command `mark-paragraph`. However, it does not have a default binding (under org-mode).

It also works on `.lisp` files. But `mark-sexp` is more appropriate.

Comment: `mark-paragraph` is generally bound to `M-h`. In org-mode, `M-h` is bound to `org-mark-element`, which seems to suit your needs.